# Embedded navbar/background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navbar, background, and style consistent through a few paged site. I have done a bit of research and found I might be able to use a server side include or the link property to embed a page in all the pages so I can change once and feel the effects on all the pages, I found the way to change the background is to add it to the body tag, but shouldn't the body tag be separate from the embedded file? I considered opening the body tag in the template file and closing it in each individual page, but that seems very bad.

Here is my unfinished template file.

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #afa7a7;
    color: white;
}
.button {
    background-color: #424242;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    padding 15px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px; 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<body>
    <a href="Main.shtml">
        <img src="images/pentagram.png"  alt="Pentagram" width="200px" height="200px" style="float: left;" />
    </a>
    <a href="Main.shtml">
        <img src="images/pentagram.png"  alt="Pentagram" width="200px" height="200px" style="float: right;" />
    </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello Michael! Welcome to the community. How are you rendering this template file? Are you using a server side language like PHP or Node? Or are you just opening it as a file in your browser?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use server side include, or the <link> element. I'm not sure how to embed it in my sitepages.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: For this task it would be awesome a server side language (pick your favourite), and a template engine. Best of luck!